# ReferenceError in qt quick controls tabview

Tags: qt, qml

My code consistently gives me a `ReferenceError`. I have tried to fix this by using

`tv.b1Text = " XD "`

as in the example, but it didn't work. How can I fix this error? I believe there's a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927587/referenceerror-in-qt-quick-controls-tabview).

Here's my code:

```
Button {
     id: b0
     text:"b1's text"
     onClicked: {
      b1.text = " XD "
     }
 }
TabView {
    id: tv
    Tab {
       id: tab1
       grid {
          Button{
              id: b1
              text:"b1's text"
              onClicked: {
                //console.log(b1.text)
                show_text()
              }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a **hierarchy** in place here and specific **scopes**. You cannot access `id`s without exposing them to higher scopes  ***or*** without going through the hierarchy, but in the *correct* way.

Let's examine your `TabView`: it has a single `Tab` element which contains a `Grid` (I'm assuming the `grid` element is actually a `Grid`!) which in turns contains the `Button` you want to modify. If you want to access it from `Button` `b0` you have to:

1. Select the tab in `tv`
2. Select the contained `item` (via the property of the same name) --> it is `Grid`
3. Select the first `item` of the `Grid` (which is the only one, our `Button`)

Hence, in the current setting, a correct code to modify your `b1` text from `b0` `clicked` signal handler, is the following:

```
tv.getTab(0).item.children[0].text = " XD "
```

Note that `data[0]` can be used in place of `children[0]` (see the [`Item`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html) element docs). As you can see here you **navigate** the hierarchy to reach the QML element to be modified.

---

As you have seen, the previous code is tedious and error prone. A **much better** approach would be using the [aliasing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/propertybinding.html#property-aliases) feature as well as Javascript to improve the overall result; other users already kindly [advised you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927587/referenceerror-in-qt-quick-controls-tabview) about that.

Comment: It looks like this question were raised because aliasing doesn't work either.