# How to access QML elements inside TabView from the function outside?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

In my QML application I have a TabView, Tabs and a few Buttons and Text fields. I need to access them using custom function from outside TabView component which is called by button from inside a Tab.

My code is pretty simple:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    function showText() {
        console.log(tabView.testText);
    }

    TabView {
        id: tabView

        property alias testText: test.text

        Tab {
            title:'tab1'

            RowLayout {
                Button {
                    text:"PRINT"

                    onClicked: {
                        showText()
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    id:test
                    text:'Test123'
                }
            }
        }

        Tab {
            title:'tab2'
        }
    }
}
```

but I get error message for the alias creation line:

```
 Invalid alias reference. Unable to find id "test"
```

What is wrong with it? I've followed similar question on SO ([ReferenceError in qt quick controls tabview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927587/referenceerror-in-qt-quick-controls-tabview)) but the code doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add one more alias like this:

```
TabView {
    id: tabView

    property var testText: { return getTab(0).tab1Text }

    Tab {
        id: tab1
        title:'tab1'

        property alias tab1Text: test.text

        RowLayout {
            Button {
                text:"PRINT"

                onClicked: {
                    showText()
                }
            }

            Text {
                id:test
                text:'Test123'
            }
        }
    }

    Tab {
        title:'tab2'
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get 'Invalid alias location' error for 'property alias testText: tab1.tab1Text' line. I think what I need to do is not weird or unusual but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Then try something like this `property var testText: { return getTab(0).tab1Text }`. Maybe it should be little fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26014890/904422) answer, `Tab` is basically a `Loader`, which means the properties you're trying to access via the alias may not have been loaded yet. `alias` has some [strict requirements](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html), one of which being that they are *"only activated once a component has been fully initialized"*:

Since you call the `show()` method from within the `Tab` that you're trying to get access to, you could just pass the data you need:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Extras 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300
    height: 600
    visible: true

    function showText(text) {
        console.log(text)
    }

    TabView {
        id: tabView

        Tab {
            title: 'tab1'

            RowLayout {
                Button {
                    text: "PRINT"

                    onClicked: {
                        showText(text)
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    id: test
                    text: 'Test123'
                }
            }
        }

        Tab {
            title: 'tab2'
        }
    }
}
```